# how to change speed of javascript transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, transition

Hello this is my code for a div sliding in from the left, how do I adjust the speed of the slide-in animation?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.leftContainer")
.css("margin-left",-$(this).width())
.animate({
    marginLeft:0
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's the 1000 in your code. See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: "1000" represents a number of milliseconds, it is the duration of your animation. Lower it to speed up the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the duration in order to change speed ( in Milli-second)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.leftContainer")
                .css("margin-left", -$(this).width())
                .animate({
                    marginLeft: 0
                }, 1000);
               //..^...change duration on here
    });
</script>
```

*Note :* `1000ms = 1sec`

Documentation : http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

```
.animate({
}, 1000); //1 second

.animate({
}, 2000); //2 seconds

.animate({
}, 5000); //5 seconds
```